# Proving bounds on analytic functions using only the Taylor expansion

Tags: real-analysis, estimation-theory

I wonder if there is a general method for obtaining bounds on an analytic function  using only its Taylor expansion (not using its special properties such as satisfying a good differential equation, etc.)

As a toy example, can we prove that $|sin(x)|\leq 1$ (or a weaker bound) only knowing that $sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots$.

Comment: Note that if you make even a small perturbation to just one coefficient of the series of $\sin x$ the resulting series will be unbounded, so any criterium of boundedness should be sensible to this.

Comment: The Riemann hypothesis is equivalent to the behavior of a simple power series. So this is a difficult problem.  In my paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.00440 I give a solution for a particular example of the problem. This can be applied to similar cases, but is not useful in the case of Riesz and Hardy and Littlewood series related to RH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such general method. You cannot see directly from the Taylor series
that $\sin x$ is bounded on the real line, or that $\exp z$ is bounded on the negative ray. Of course what I stated is not a theorem, but just think how this boundedness criterion could possibly look: ANY change in ONE coefficient of the
series destroys the property.